# python 3.0 readline() random jump

Tags: python, text-files, pydev, readlines

I am reading a txt file line by line using **python 3** built-in **readline() function**. This file contains employees information in blocks and it looks like this:

> First name Jack \n
>   Last name Garcia \n
>   Manager name Smith \n
>   Description this is the description of the employee \n
>   bla bla bla bla \n
>   bla bla bla bla \n
>   bla bla bla bla. \n
>   Salary 25000\n

My code looks like this:

```
with open(os.path.join(INPUT_FOLDER, filename)) as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        if line.upper().startswith('DESCRIPTION'):
            description = line.split('DESCRIPTION')[1].strip()
            line = input_file.readline()
            while not line.upper().startswith('SALARY'):
                ...
```

I get the expected value in `description` variable but when the `input_file.readline()` statement is executed, it jumps 5 lines farther!! So I can't complete the rest of the description properly. What makes me mad is that I have read other employees information blocks previously in the same file and everything works correctly.

I am executing the script under Eclipse using **pydev 2.7.1**

Has anyone deal with a similar problem? Is it related with the IDE, python version, ...?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the code inside the `while` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix file iteration and readline(). The [Built-In Types doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) for file.next() says:

"In order to make a for loop the most efficient way of looping over the lines of a file (a very common operation), the next() method uses a hidden read-ahead buffer. As a consequence of using a read-ahead buffer, combining next() with other file methods (like readline()) does not work right. However, using seek() to reposition the file to an absolute position will flush the read-ahead buffer."

```
with open(os.path.join(INPUT_FOLDER, filename)) as input_file:
    while True:
        line = input_file.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        if line.upper().startswith('DESCRIPTION'):
            description = line.split('DESCRIPTION')[1].strip()
            line = input_file.readline()
            while not line.upper().startswith(SALARY):
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are comparing on uppercase but spliting on unmodified case :

```
line.split('DESCRIPTION')
```

Also, this

```
line = input_file.readline()
while not line.upper().startswith(SALARY):
```

does not seem to be appended to your description variable.

Your probably need to add

```
line = input_file.readline()
while not line.upper().startswith(SALARY):
    description += line
    line = input_file.readline()
```